# Seeding pseudo-random function with limited set of C99 standard functions

Tags: linux, macos, openssl, c99

I'm working on school project, particularly, implementing `openssl` `genrsa` command.
School project limits available functions to `open, close, read, write, malloc, free`.

One of the option flags for `genrsa` command is `rand`. As I understand from man page, this flag is intended to be used on a systems that does not have API for "machine noise", like `dev/urandom` on linux systems, so that seed can be generated from file or a socket.

When repeatedly seeded with an empty file `openssl` `genrsa` does not output the same key, which probably means that it actually uses some other random seed.

**The question**: How do I get a randomized output, as does `openssl` `genrsa` command seeded with an empty file, without using `dev/random` or `dev/urandom` and with a limited set of functions as specified above?

Comment: Typical is to use a high-res clock.  Every time you run, the time will be different.

Comment: Unfortunately, clock is not amongst allowed functions

Comment: Run a PRNG seeded from a file.  Write the new back to the file so the next output is different.

Comment: File may be read-only

Comment: So far the only way I can see is using garbage data from an allocated memory. Obviously this is a very poor solution.

Comment: If file is read-only, why are you allowed use of the write function?

Comment: I don't see how both are related. You mean write to a new file? Anyways, I don't think exposing internal state of PRNG function to external file is a good idea.